# What is the name of the viewmodel here?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have this piece of code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {    
        public CViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }            
        public MainWindow()
        {    
            try
            {
                 InitializeComponent(); // create VM first time
                 try
                 {                         
                     ViewModel = new CViewModel(); // create VM 2nd time
                     ViewModel.topGrid = TopGrid;
```

and in the corresponding XAML I have this:

```
<Window
    .....
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:CCalc"
    ....
    x:Class="CCalc.MainWindow"
   ....>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <c:CViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

I can see that the CViewModel instance is created twice: once by the XAML code because of **InitializeComponent** and once by  **new CViewModel()**.
So I erase that line of code. But how can I then set **topGrid**?
in other words: what is the name of the viewmodel that is my data context?

Comment: Why do you need to get to the View Model in code-behind?

Comment: Because later on in the program  I do a "topGrid.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();"

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many instances as you like of a normal class. The two view-model instances are different. It's up to you which one you want to use.

To set your topGrid, you have to access your ViewModel in code. This can be done in two ways :

```
// using the one declared in xaml file

    CViewModel vm = (CViewModel)this.DataContext;
    vm.topGrid = TopGrid;

// using a new one

CViewModel vm = new CViewModel();
vm.topGrid = TopGrid;    
this.DataContext = vm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `ViewModel` property to:

```
public CViewModel ViewModel
{
get { return DataContext as CViewModel; }
set { DataContext = value; }
}
```

And on main You can do something like this:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ViewModel = new CViewModel();
  ViewModel.topGrid = TopGrid;
}
```

Comment: But then  I would build up a CViewModel twice, would I not?

Comment: Yes. I should remove from xaml this part 
    <Window.DataContext>
        <c:CViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

Answer (score 0):

you can access to viewmodel using the datacontext

```
(this.DataContext as CViewModel).topGrid = TopGrid;
```

You can test it before to be sure it's not nul.

```
CViewModel model = (this.DataContext as CViewModel);
if (model != null)
{
    model.topGrid = TopGrid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `dataContext` as `new CViewModel`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    public CViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }            
    public MainWindow()
    {    
        try
        {
             InitializeComponent(); // create VM first time
             try
             {          
                 DataContext = new CViewModel();
```

And then as @Xaruth say call

```
(this.DataContext as CViewModel).topGrid = TopGrid;
```